# Shemona Vachamishim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred fifty-eight?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point between twenty-four hours and a few days from now, I will:*

- *Vote up all interesting and relevant answers.*
- *Accept what I consider the "best" answer.*
- *Move on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.torah.org/learning/perceptions/5766/terumah.html

The Aron was made out of 3 boxes - 1 inside the next. 3 x Elokim = **258** which is also the Gematria of Charan. Betzalel made three arks corresponding to three times Elokim.

Charan, is the name of the city from which Avraham made Aliyah. It was in the city of Charan, at the age of seventy, that Hashem first appeared to Avraham and commanded him to travel to what was at that time Eretz Canaan.